# jQuery: how do I get a div to go away after 1 second? (jQuery 1.3.2)

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to hide a div after 1 second?

EDIT:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $j('.flotymessage').fadeOut(300);
    },1000);
```

doesn't work =\
.floatymessage is a div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) after one second (1000 milliseconds).

```
setTimeout(function(){$('div#divID').hide();},1000);
```

Comment: why doesn't this work?  setTimeout(function(){
  $j('.flotymessage').fadeOut(300);
  },1000);

Comment: @DerNalia - In your other questions, you have it spelled `floatymessage` not `flotymessage`.

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery delay() function](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is the way to go. The parameter to `delay()` is in milliseconds so you need 1000 ms to get 1s.

```
$('div.flotymessage').delay(1000).hide("slow"); // hide it slowly
$('div.flotymessage').delay(1000).hide(1); // hide it after 1 ms (pretty much instantly)
```

An alternative to `hide()`ing your `<div>` is to assign it a new class that would have the CSS ready for the hiding. Let me know if you need me to elaborate on that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I actually saw this, but I have jQuery 1.3.2, I wall add that to the title

Comment: This will not work, because `.delay()` only works ahead of calls that have an animation queue. For example, it would work if you did `$('div.flotymessage').delay(1000).hide("slow");`

Comment: @patrick dw... thanks for the correction. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if the above solution doesnt work for you (cant tell why, it should work) you can always try .delay
so

```
setTimeout(function(){
$j('.flotymessage').fadeOut(300);
},1000);
```

would become

```
$j('.flotymessage').delay(1000).fadeOut(300);
```

€: im sorry i was too slow^^